# Run executable from resources

Tags: c#, resources

I already made console application using C++. Now I want to add my application to my Visual Studio C# resources to make it run each time from startup. I had use GetManifestResourceStream but does not works for me. I also set Embedded Resource in my build action property.

```
Assembly asm = null;
using (Stream manifestResourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.Resources.MyApplication.exe"))
{
    if (manifestResourceStream != null)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] numArray = new byte[manifestResourceStream.Length];
            manifestResourceStream.Read(numArray, 0, numArray.Length);
            MessageBox.Show("Going to run!");
            asm = Assembly.Load(numArray);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I'm failed!");
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("I'm failed! from first if");
}

if (asm != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ASM not null");
    var entryPoint = asm.EntryPoint;
    var commandArgs = new string[1];
    var returnValue = entryPoint.Invoke(null, commandArgs);
}
```

From what I seen here, I put those four messagebox in different scope for me to easy debug. However, I had no ideas why those first three messagebox(Accept not null) will pop out.

My Goal: I want to run a executable file at the same time run another executable. I don't want use ProcessStart as it separates two file.

Comment: You can't load *.exe file with GetManifestResourceStream, what exactly your goal? are you just want to running the exe?

Comment: Is the console app written in managed or unmanaged c++?

Comment: This is not possible.  A C++ compiler generates native code, Windows *requires* it to run from a file on disk.  Fundamental about the way the operating system works.  A very common way to deploy a single file with multiple programs inside of it is one you already know, everybody calls it "setup.exe".